# Sudden - 'The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient' in working project

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an ASP.Net Webforms website running in IIS on a Windows Server.
Also on this server is the SQL server.

Everything has been working fine with the site but now I am seeing issues with using a DataAdapter to fill a table.

So here is some code, please note it's just basic outline of code as actual code contains confidential information.

```
public List<Summary> Fetch(string Connection, int parameter1, int parameter2, bool parameter3)
{
     List<Summary> collection = new List<Summary>();

     using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection))
     {
        using (SqlCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()) // Result is complex
        {
            dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             
            //
            // Code to add parameters and set commandText goes here
            //

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand))
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                DataRow row;

                try
                {
                  da.Fill(table);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                   // Log error
                }
                
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    row = table.Rows[i];
                    Summary data = Populate(row);
                    collection.Add(data);
                }
            }
         }
     }
     return collection;
}
```

The above is in a library and is called like this in the Web Forms site.

```
var Summaries = MyLibrary.Fetch(ConnectionString, 1, 111, false);
```

So as I say, everything was working fine. Now, all of a sudden the above has stopped working and `Summaries` is always empty.

To investigate I tried the following.

Created a test using xUnit with the same parameters used by the website. These were captured during debugging to ensure they matched.
The result returned 1 item.

I then ran the stored procedure in SQL management Studio and it matched the xUnit test with 1 item returned.

I then checked SQL Profiler and this is where things seemed a little odd. Nothing was being recorded in the trace when the web-forms was calling the library.

So both the web-site and xUnit test were using the same library, passing the same parameters  and yet one worked and the other didn't... very odd.

As a last resort, I added the library project to the Web Forms project and proceeded to debug through that... then I found the error.

```
da.Fill(table);
```

The above line generated the following exception.

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

Having a look around here on stack, I saw many responses with I need to install a certificate.

My question is, if this is the case then why and why now?
Nothing has changed in the code from when it was working till now. The web-site and SQL server are on the same windows server. Also, why does the xunit test work without it and the website does not when I am debugging on the same machine!

The only items that I now has changed is install of .Net 6 and patch Tuesday resulted in some updates and a restart of the server.

Comment: Why now? All certificates have an expiry and this may have just happened. I would suggest viewing the certificate chain (https://www.top-password.com/blog/view-installed-certificates-in-windows-10-8-7/) and double checking that none have expired. If you are using a CA like StartSSL then the root CA is no longer trusted (they were doing some bad things and got correctly punished by Microsoft/Google/everyone)

Comment: So why does the web-forms project care about this certificate but the xunit test project does not, running on the same machine using the same connection string?

Comment: SQL Server is installed with a self-signed X.509 certificate so if you used `encrypt=true` or similar in your connection strings you would normally see errors like this from the very beginning - unless you also had `trustServerCertificate=true`. That this is only happening now suggests one or more of: 1) the connection string has changed; 2) the SQL Server instance had a CA-provided certificate whose ICA/root certificate has expired (e.g.: Let's Encrypt); 3) the SQL Server instance had a CA-provided certificate whose CA is no longer trusted due to Microsoft Trusted Root Certificate updates.

Comment: `encrypt=true` and `trustServerCertificate=true` have never been in the connection string. Also, if the web forms site and SQL server are on the same machine then surly the certificate is already there?. Still doesn't explain why 2 separate projects calling the same library using the same connection string have different outcomes. In other words, why does my xunit test not require the certificate?

Comment: I started seeing this issue after upgrading `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` from `3.0.1` to `4.0.0`

Comment: I started seeing this same issue and it's even WORSE.  I reverted all my code back to v2.0.0 of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, and what was working before is now completely broken with this certificate chain issue. It's almost as if simply using v4.0.0 of the library, even temporarily, has permanently corrupted something.

Comment: I'm also seeing a new error when calling SqlConnection.OpenAsync: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary." This started happening with use of v4.0.0 of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, but does not resolve after reverting back to v2.0.0.

Comment: I had also the same issue after updating Dapper nuget package which use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.0 is using ENCRYPT=True by default. Either you put a certificate on the server (not a self signed one) or you put

TrustServerCertificate=Yes;

on the connection string.

Comment: Thank you, this provided a solution and the why.

Comment: This doesn't explain why this issue has suddenly started happening to me after using v4.0.0 of the library, but it continues to happen after reverting back to version 2.0. It's almost as if using v.4.0 has modified something in my system permanently.

Comment: I've tried every combination of Encrypt, TrustServerCertificate, and nothing is behaving like it used to. Seeing an error that started with v4.0.0, and now persists even after revering back to v2. When I call SqlConnection.OpenAsync, I get an error saying "The given key was not present in the dictionary.", which makes no sense coming from OpenAsync. I wonder if it has something to do with the native SNI assembly.

Comment: I also experienced a Trusted SSL issue when opening my connection to the SQL server. Curiously, this started after I switched to Core 6.0. my previous project using Core 5.0 on the same SQL Server does not do this and does not require the TrustServerCertificate in the connection string.

Answer (score 22):

I hit this issue as well. Net 6.0

It suddenly started occurring when I upgraded **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**

FROM Version="6.0.0" to Version="6.0.1"

I added ***Encrypt*** and ***TrustServerCertificate*** to connection string.

data source=(local);Initial Catalog=XXXXXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;***Encrypt***=True;***TrustServerCertificate***=True

Comment: It's fair to say that while adding TrustServerCertificate=True enables the current connection, or setting Encyrpt=False returns to the prior default, it's worth considering updating our sql server setup to server the connection from an actual certificate.

Comment: Thanks, I just hit the exact same problem, and worked around it by appending `TrustServerCertificate=True` to our connection string.

Comment: Before anyone else needs to mald about this: "TrustServerCertificate" is only accepted if "Encrypt" exists in the connection string. By default encryption is enabled now with ODBC driver version 18 and just adding TrustServerCertificate without Encrypt will not do the job

Comment: For me, adding Encrypt=False OR adding TrustServerCertificate=True worked (using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 7.0)

Comment: I got the error after migrating from .net6 to .net7. Same fix noted above worked.
Any idea what caused it suddenly?

Answer (score 3):

I have  added **`TrustServerCertificate=True`** in my `ConnectionStrings` to solve this issue. This is how it looks like

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost; Database=GreenProducts;Trusted_Connection=True; TrustServerCertificate=True"
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a copy of Pieter van Kampen's answer

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly got the same problem when first upgrading Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to 4.x.x. I reverted back to 2.0.1 and the same problem was present.

I then removed all "bin" and "obj" folders for each project. And then executed a "dotnet restore". After that it worked as before.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to others, we got this error after upgrading  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer from 2.2.6 to 6.0.5 and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient from 3.0.0 to 4.1.0.

However, in our case removing Microsoft.Data.SqlClient fixed the issue.

I noticed that Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer listed a dependency of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 2.1.4 in the solution explorer, maybe that is why removing the other one worked.

Answer (score 0):

What made my scenario a bit different is that I have a multi-layer application - so, my repository layer is a stand-alone project within my solution (note: I am using .NET 6/7 for my projects).

I know the problem was definitely on my side, but the following command did not work the way I wanted:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext name="MyConnectionString" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir MyModels
```

So I ended up doing the following:

1. Make sure your connection string is correctly configured in your startup project's `appsettings.json` file. As mentioned in the answers above, add the following to your connection string `Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True`. My connection string ended up looking like this: `Server=SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyExampleDB;Trusted_Connection=True;user id=TheUser;password=MySuperStrongPassword;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True` (obviously integrated security will also fine)
2. Open the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022
3. `cd` into the repo project (or the project where you need the context and models to reside)
4. Run this command: `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold name="MyConnectionString" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o MyModels -f --startup-project ..\MyProject.API`
5. Done - the generated models and DBContext should be in your repo project.

Take Note:

Remember to have `dotnet ef` installed. If not, run this command in the Developer Command Prompt `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`. If an update is required run `dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef`.
For more info on the above: Look at [Entity Framework Core tools reference - .NET Core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet)

If the scaffolding was successful, but you come across this message:
`The database user has not been granted 'VIEW DEFINITION' rights. Scaffolding requires these rights to construct the Entity Framework model correctly. Without these rights, parts of the scaffolded model may be missing, resulting in incorrect interactions between Entity Framework and the database at runtime.` - have a look at David Browne's answer here: [Entity Framework Core 7.0.2 "The database user has not been granted 'VIEW DEFINITION' rights"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75270302/entity-framework-core-7-0-2-the-database-user-has-not-been-granted-view-defini)

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score -2):

I was getting error on EF Core 7 while applying migrations.
I have changed connection string name and the issue solved.

Comment: The connection string *name* itself doesn't have any influence on this issue.