# SSL provide error: When I run my API code then I founded a runtime error

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssl, .net-6.0

> **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException **(0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090325): The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

```
using WebApplication2.Data;
using WebApplication2.Model.Domain;


namespace WebApplication2.Repositories
{
    public class RegionRepository : IRegionRepository
    {
        private readonly WalksDbContext walksDbContext;
        public RegionRepository(WalksDbContext walksDbContext)
        {
            this.walksDbContext = walksDbContext;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Region> GetAll()
        {
            return walksDbContext.Regions.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do these links answer your question? ["The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when connecting DB in VM Role](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17615260/113116), ['The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient' in working project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70112568/113116)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Helen, this is not answer related to my topic.

Comment: Are you sure your issue is not the same? The error message implies that your backend SQL server uses a self-signed SSL certificate. The linked Q&As suggest either installing a proper cert from a trusted CA, or changing the connection string to trust your custom cert.

Comment: @Helen I will check once again then I'll tell you.

Comment: Hi @Helen, for this error I used local database so SSL provide error is resolved.
my local database name is **(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB** and also change in **appsetting.json** like this '{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "NzWalks": "server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;database=NzWalksDb;trusted_connection=true"
  }
}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I used local database so SSL provide error is resolved. my local database name is (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB and also change in appsetting.json like this

```
    { 
     "Logging": {
         "LogLevel": { 
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
      }
 },
 "AllowedHosts": "*",
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "NzWalks": "server=
 (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;database=NzWalksDb;trusted_connection=true"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.0 is uses ENCRYPT=True by default.

Either you put a certificate on the server (not a self signed one) or you add

```
TrustServerCertificate=Yes;
```

to the connection string.