# Entity Framework Core 7.0.2 "The database user has not been granted 'VIEW DEFINITION' rights"

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using the `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` command to create my database context. Since updating the toolchain to v7.0.2, I am getting this warning in the output:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
The database user has not been granted 'VIEW DEFINITION' rights. Scaffolding requires these rights to construct the Entity Framework model correctly. Without these rights, parts of the scaffolded model may be missing, resulting in incorrect interactions between Entity Framework and the database at runtime.
```

The database user is in the `db_owner` role, but furthermore I have manually executed against the `Master` database

```
grant view any definition to [dbusername]
```

The warning message remains. Can anyone assist with this?

Comment: `db_owner` role membership should be sufficient unless the permission was explicitly denied. Try verifying the permission by running `SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(NULL,NULL,'VIEW ANY DEFINITION');` in the context of the user database when logged in as dbusername.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and noticed, that when my DB name contains a dot ("Some.Database" for example) it triggers this bug. EF Core does:

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(DB_NAME(), 'DATABASE', 'VIEW DEFINITION');
```

On new empty db named "Some.Database" this returns 0, if i change the name to "Some_Database" it returns 1 making EF happy.

Comment: Fixed in EF Core 8.0 https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29610

Answer (score 0):

Technically user's don't need VIEW DEFINITION to see metadata.  Normally metadata visibility for a table is granted to users who have any other permission on the table.  See [Metadata Visibility Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/metadata-visibility-configuration?view=sql-server-ver16).

The VIEW DEFINITION permission acts as an override to change this behavior, granting metadata access to a user who otherwise would have it, or denying it a user who otherwise would.

So checking for VIEW DEFINITION is not the same as checking if a user can see the metadata.  You can start by checking the grants for an applicable DENY of VIEW DEFINITION, and if a user isn't subject to a DENY and has SELECT on the table, or it's schema or database, then the user will have metadata visibility.

```
select state_desc,
       permission_name,
       user_name(grantee_principal_id) grantee, 
       case when class = 0 then 'DATABASE'
            when class = 1 then  concat(quotename(schema_name(o.schema_id)),'.',quotename(object_name(o.object_id)))
        end target
from sys.database_permissions p
left join sys.objects o
  on o.object_id = p.major_id 
--where state = 'D'
```

Comment: HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME should be useful, I think?

Comment: There are no DENYs and the appropriate VIEW DEFINITION grant is present. I don't think this is a SQL Server issue, more something out of whack with EF.

Comment: @ErikEJ HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME doesn't help because it VIEW DEFINITION is rarely granted directly.  It doesn't show if you have VIEW DEFINITION as a consequence of having SELECT, which is the most common case.

Comment: Then EF is connecting as another user.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft that is not how I read the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/has-perms-by-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: VIEW DEFINITION is just weird because it doesn’t need to be GRANTed.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft got it, but has_perms_by_name should not care according to the docs

Comment: Good point.  The error message is a bit off, VIEW DEFINITION is not required for metadata visibility, which is normally implicit with some other permission.  VIEW DEFINITION is a kind of override to alter the metadata visibility rules.  I'll update the answer to clarify.